# How to select multiple images in Photos Library using ELCImagePickerController and ALAssetsLibrary?

Tags: iphone, ios, elcimagepickercontroller

As iam a newbie please tell me how to select multiple images in the photos library. I have been searching the solution since a week, but not finding a relevant one for my code.
As per my code, iam able to select one image at a time. This is how my code looks as of now:

```
-(IBAction) photosClick
{
    ipc= [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    ipc.delegate= self;
    ipc.sourceType= UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController: ipc animated:YES];
}
-(void) imagepickerControllerDidCancel: (UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];
    [picker release];
}
-(void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image;
    NSURL *mediaURL;
    mediaURL= (NSURL *)[info valueForKey: UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    NSString *imagePath= [[NSString alloc] init];
    imagePath= [mediaURL absoluteString];
    NSLog(@"path of the image is: %@", imagePath);
    image= (UIImage *) [info valueForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    imageView.image= image;
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
-(void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel: (UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Please help me with this problem by editing my code so that i can understand well. I have been stuck with this and not getting any solution.

Comment: Read [Documentation](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController) of **ELCImagePickerController**. You are not using **ELCImagePickerController** in your code.

Comment: Please help me how to use this in my code. As aim new to iPhone app development, i need guidance.

Comment: @vanya- See IronMan's answer. [QBImagePickerController](https://github.com/questbeat/QBImagePickerController) is easy ... download the sample code and run it.

Comment: I downloaded the sample code of QBImagePickerController and implemented in my code. But iam getting error for these 2 lines as 1. property 'delegate' and 'allowsMutlipleSelection' not found for object QBImagePickerController.    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;

Comment: Please help me with this issue, for 'delegate' property iam getting the error though i have included the QBImagePickerControllerDelegate in the interface section. And regarding the'allowsMultipleSelection' i have no idea y its showing the error.

Answer (score 2):

I can offer you a better library than the ELC Image Picker Controller. This has been used in multiple apps and is far more customizable.

Please check [QBImagePickerController](https://github.com/questbeat/QBImagePickerController)

Comment: I downloaded the sample code of QBImagePickerController and implemented in my code. But iam getting error for these 2 lines as 1. property 'delegate' and 'allowsMutlipleSelection' not found for object QBImagePickerController. imagePickerController.delegate = self; imagePickerController.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;

Comment: Please help me with this issue, for 'delegate' property iam getting the error though i have included the QBImagePickerControllerDelegate in the interface section. And regarding the'allowsMultipleSelection' i have no idea y its showing the error

Comment: There is a sample code pls consult it ... Also if you have taken it from the interface builder have you connected it ?

Comment: In interface builder i have connected. The error is in the code.

Comment: The only error which iam getting in my code is: synthesize of 'weak' property is only allowed in arc or gc mode. I have enabled the ARC mode. even then iam getting the same error.